# Plot two functions in the same graph r mirt

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, lattice

I estimated two marginal reliability by using mirt package for two different IRT Graded Response Models. However, I would like to visualized them in the same graph.

```
#Marginal Reliability of polytomous ModF1
MreliabF1<- marginal_rxx(POLY.MODf1)
plot(POLY.MODf1 = 'rxx', theta_lim = c(-3, 3), 
    main="" )
#Marginal Reliability of ModF2
MreliabF2<- marginal_rxx(POLY.MODf2)
plot(POLY.MODf2, type = 'rxx', theta_lim = c(-3, 3), 
     main="" )
```

These syntax help me to generate two graph separately.

[image]

[image]

How can I combine them? Could ExtraLattice be a useful package?

Comment: See https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/

Comment: please add example data see [https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example)